# .svc handler mappings for .Net 2.0 app pool working after a .Net 3.0 install?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7, application-pool, svc

This is odd.  I have a website running under a .Net 2.0 app pool (Integrated mode) and couldn't connect to a WCF service on the site.  A message reading "The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler" would pop up whenever I navigated to the URL on my box.

I checked the handler mappings in IIS for this website's .svc extension and saw entries reading `svc-Integrated-4.0, svc-ISAPI-2.0- and svc-ISAPI-2.0-64`.  But nothing for svc-Integrated, which I assume was the problem.

I followed the ServiceModelReg -i recommendations in [this post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2008/12/01/wcf-on-iis7-on-vista-adding-svc-handler.aspx), but there was no instance of that executible in my Framework\v2.0.5027 subfolder.  So I went up a level and found it in my Framework\3.0.0 folder, and ran it from there.  Lo and behold, things work now and there's a new handler for svc-Integrated in the mappings section.

But my question is: if I installed this for .Net 3.0, how is a .Net 2.0 app pool making use of it?  I thought there would be a compatibility issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I installed this for .Net 3.0, how is a .Net 2.0 app pool making use of it? I thought there would be a compatibility issue?

No, the .NET Framework 3.0 [still uses the 2.0 CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx), so using a 2.0 AppPool is appropriate.

IIS AppPools indicate the CLR version, not the Framework version.